# Tricky python control flow

Tags: python, if-statement, control-flow

I was working on a project and have replicated my doubt by a simple example. I am unable to understand the control structure of the following python code snippet.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
for item in list1:
    if item == 3:
        print("Found")
        # break
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Note: Please note that the indentation of the else part is intentionally kept so and I thought it would through an error but it gives the following output:

```
Found
Not found
```

Also if we uncomment '**# break**' the output is:

```
Found
```

Why isn't this code throwing an error.If it's working as per if else conditions then the expected output should be:

```
Not Found
Not Found
Found
Not Found
Not Found
```

Comment: Python `for` loops can have an `else` clause. See the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Answer (score 1):

The `else` condition in the code is for the `for` loop and not from the if statement since that you are getting `Not found` in the end because it's getting executed after the last `for` loop iteration.
In this code the indentation of the `else` is for the if

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
for item in list1:
    if item == 3:
        print("Found")
        # break
    else:
        print("Not found")
```

and that outputs

```
Not found
Not found
Found
Not found
Not found
```

Answer (score 0):

to understand it more clearly place another else loop for if block... current else block is for for loop